# Hapi/Joi Cannot apply rules to empty ruleset or the last rule added does not support rule properties

Tags: hapi

I am trying to display a custom message when users didn't put a password during login. This worked fine when I don't have a custom message for the password:

```
const ValidationSchemas = Joi.object({
  name: Joi.string().min(6).required().messages({
      "string.empty":"Display name cannot be empty",
      "string.min":"Min 6 characteers"
  }).optional(),
  email: Joi.string().min(6).required().email().message("Must be a valid email address"),
  password:Joi.string().min(6).required()
})
```

But the moment I tried to have a custom message for the empty password field, I got an error stating - Cannot apply rules to empty ruleset or the last rule added does not support rule properties

Here is the code that I am trying to have a custom message for the password:

```
const ValidationSchemas = Joi.object({
  name: Joi.string().min(6).required().messages({
      "string.empty":"Display name cannot be empty",
      "string.min":"Min 6 characteers"
  }).optional(),
  email: Joi.string().min(6).required().email().message("Must be a valid email address"),
  password:Joi.string().min(6).required().message("Password is required!")
})
```

How do I have a custom message for the password? many thanks in advance and greatly appreciate any help. thanks

Comment: reported: https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/2868

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below example in your code:

```js
const ValidationSchemas = Joi.object({    
    name: Joi.string()  
      .min(6)
      .required()
      .messages({
        'string.empty': 'Display name cannot be empty',
        'string.min': 'Min 6 characters',
      })
      .optional(),
    email: Joi.string().min(6).required().email().message('Must be a valid email address'),
    password: Joi.string().required().min(6).message('Password is required!'),
  });
```

Comment: Best to indicate what your solution actually is. How does this differ from the block of code that's in the description?

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue, i later found out that using `message()` will terminate the current ruleset and cannot be followed by another rule option.

So instead of using `message()`, i used this: `messages({ 'any.only': 'GENERAL_MESSAGE_HERE' })`

Hence, in your case, you should change your code to this:

```js
const ValidationSchemas = Joi.object({
      name: Joi.string()
        .min(6)
        .required()
        .messages({
          'string.empty': 'Display name cannot be empty',
          'string.min': 'Min 6 characteers',
        })
        .optional(),
      email: Joi.string().min(6).required().email().messages({
        'any.only': 'Must be a valid email address',
      }),
      password: Joi.string()
        .min(6)
        .required()
        .messages({ 'any.only': 'Password is required!' }),
    })
```

Comment: Feel like this is a better solution, since the above accepted one (simply reordering some of the properties) did not work for me